# Javascript for setting the date of each upcoming day of the week?

Tags: javascript

So I found this little snippet of javascript that sets the date for the very next calendar Saturday

```
var nextSaturday = new Date();
nextSaturday.setDate(now.getDate() + (6 - 1 - now.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
```

I can't wrap my head around this math. How would I change this for each day of the week? For instance, what would be changed to get the date for Monday?

Comment: I would assume change `6` to `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider today, Friday, February 24th, 2023, the 5th day of the week.

```js
const today = new Date('2023-02-24')
console.log(today.getDate())    // 24
console.log(today.getDay())     // 5
```

Now we want to find the next Saturday (tomorrow, the 25th, the 6th day of the week).

```js
const saturday = new Date('2023-02-25')
console.log(saturday.getDay())     // 6
```

To advance from Friday to Saturday, we need to increment by 1 day. Naively, we could do this (note use of `6` for `saturday.getDay()`):

```
let nextSaturday = new Date()
nextSaturday.setDate(today.getDate() + 6 - today.getDay())
console.log(nextSaturday.getDate())    // 25
```

The issue comes when we want to find the next Monday. In this case, we might try (`getDay()` returns `1` for Monday):

```
let nextMonday = new Date()
nextMonday.setDate(today.getDate() + 1 - today.getDay())
console.log(nextMonday.getDate())     // 20
```

This has gone back in time because Monday's day number is less than Friday's so we end up subtracting 4 from today's date (`Monday.getDay() - today.getDay() = 1 - 5 = -4`). To work around this, we need to make sure that the number is always positive, which we do by adding 7, and then taking the result modulo 7 (note in some languages modulo always returns a positive number so adding 7 is not necessary):

```
nextMonday = new Date()
nextMonday.setDate(today.getDate() + (1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7)
console.log(nextMonday.getDate())     // 27
```

Now this all works fine except for one case, when we want to find the next Friday (the 3rd of March). In this case, our issue is that `(5 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7 == 0`, so we will get today's date again.

```
let nextFriday = new Date()
nextFriday.setDate(today.getDate() + (5 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7)
console.log(nextFriday.getDate())     // 24
```

To work around this, we need to change the code so that instead of adding 0 in this case, it adds 7 (i.e. we need a range of `7,1..6` instead of `0..6`). The way to do this is to subtract 1 from `5 - today.getDay() + 7` before the modulo and then add it back afterwards:

```
nextFriday = new Date()
nextFriday.setDate(today.getDate() + (5 - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1)
console.log(nextFriday.getDate())     // 3
```

In general, to adapt this code for any given day of the week, replace the `5` in the above code with the value of [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ...) for that day of the week.

Full code snippet:

```js
const today = new Date('2023-02-24')
console.log(today.getDate())    // 24
console.log(today.getDay())     // 5

const saturday = new Date('2023-02-25')
console.log(saturday.getDay())     // 6

let nextSaturday = new Date()
nextSaturday.setDate(today.getDate() + 6 - today.getDay())
console.log(nextSaturday.getDate())    // 25

let nextMonday = new Date()
nextMonday.setDate(today.getDate() + 1 - today.getDay())
console.log(nextMonday.getDate())     // 20  

nextMonday = new Date()
nextMonday.setDate(today.getDate() + (1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7)
console.log(nextMonday.getDate())     // 27 

let nextFriday = new Date()
nextFriday.setDate(today.getDate() + (5 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7)
console.log(nextFriday.getDate())     // 24

nextFriday = new Date()
nextFriday.setDate(today.getDate() + (5 - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1)
console.log(nextFriday.getDate())     // 3
```